# Asp.net sending html emails with MVC.Postal. Clients seeing raw html in the emails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-email, postal

We are trying to send html email via MVC postal nuget package. The problem is some clients are seeing raw html tags in the email. Sending the same email to gmail and a few other providers causes no issues. Any ideas?

We are following the simple conventions as per the docs.

### Email.cshtml

```
@model InviteViewModel

To: @Model.Email
From: invites@domain.com
Subject: @Model.Subject
Views: Html
```

### Email.Html.cshtml

```
@model InviteViewModel

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
bla blah......
</html>
```

Comment: I'm facing this issue too but with Postal.AspNetCore, figured it out yet?

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` of the `*.Html.cshtml` file must be at the topmost line of the file.

**Email.Html.cshtml**

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

@model InviteViewModel    

<html>
bla blah......
</html>
```